# A MATLAB guy wants to do a project in ROS

Tags: ros, matlab, mapping, c++, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Background + Objective!:
I am a MATLAB/Computer Vision guy and I want to start to write a some piece of useful code in ROS. I have a basic understanding of ROS (topic, node, message ...). What I want to do is to write a 3D version of local occupancy grid map in 5-6 months (It will be as a part of my PhD thesis). Result of 2d version of local occupancy grid map that I have done in MATLAB is available in here: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYkHxVOPGgA)

Problems!:
The problem is ROS is a bit confusing for me. Maybe because of the lack of my skills in ROS and CPP. In my view MATLAB is a small body with huge amount of muscles (lots of codes, toolboxes and a great source of helps for writing small project) and ROS has a just big skeleton (very good structured for making big/real projects) and building every chunk of muscle for filling this skeleton will needs a lots of time and efforts... . Most of my questions are regarding programming skills in CPP and ROS. Some one please give me a big picture of what should I do:

- Is it possible to directly write/implement a medium size cpp project in ROS or should I use an ide? e.g. Qt creator, Eclipse ...
- how can I debug my codes in ROS?
- how can I visualize 3D grids in ROS/CPP?

P.S. I will add more questions later.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193838/a-matlab-guy-wants-to-do-a-project-in-ros/) by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you want to use ROS not ROS with Matlab

Have a look on these  packages which will be useful [3d_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/3d_navigation) , [octomap_server](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server) and [octomap_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping)

you dont need IDE to manage project but Qtcreator comes good for autofilling and debugging.

**Visualize 3D grids in ROS/CPP**

[RVIZ](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) can do that for you, it was quite easy .

**Debugging ROS in Qtcreator**

[this QA is very helpful](http://answers.ros.org/question/34966/debugging-ros-package-with-qtcreator/)

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on 2014-10-01**:
Yes. I want to use ROS. Thank you for you useful information. I will have more questions to ask, ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know a lot about MATLAB and ROS, but Ren Sang Nah of Mathworks [presented a new MATLAB-ROS I/O package at ROSCon this year](http://vimeo.com/107520868). Might be worth a look for you.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1